# can I cache https resources in browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, caching, https, browser-cache

I am currently working on improving the performance of my asp.net mvc 4 application. The entire site is in https so all static resources such as javascript, css, images etc are supplied over https.

I have read different feedback in that its not possible to cache such resources in the clients browser - is this correct? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

Default is yes for IE and Firefox.
Belive same for Chrome.

To check settings.

IE : Options, Advanced, "do not save encrypted pages to disk"

Firefox : about:config, browser.cache.disk_cache_ssl